# Web Language Model API breaks connection frequently

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using Azure's [Web Language Model API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/55de9ca4e597ed1fd4e2f104/operations/55de9ca4e597ed19b0de8a4e). I am using the "Standard" (non free) version of the API. I am facing two problems:

(1) The speed of service requests is 1000 calls/minute much lower than 1000 services per second as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/web-language-model/).

(2) The connection breaks frequently, after 10-15k calls either I get "Connection Timed Out" or "Connection Reset by Peer" errors.

Here's the error I am receiving:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py in read(self, len, buffer)
    573         """
    574         if buffer is not None:
--> 575             v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    576         else:
    577             v = self._sslobj.read(len)

TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

===

After the initial request to connect, all my post requests are made to the same connection.

Here's a code snippet of how I am trying to make the queries:

```
self.params = urllib.parse.urlencode(dict({
    # Request parameters
    'model': 'body',
    'order': 3,
}))

self.conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')

jsonq = {"queries": [{"words": words, "word": word}]}
self.conn.request("POST", "/text/weblm/v1.0/calculateConditionalProbability?%s"  %self.params, str(jsonq), self.headers)
output = json.loads(self.conn.getresponse().read().decode())
```